# What is the size allocated to a self referential structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
struct node 
{ 
    int data1; 
    int data2;
    struct node* link; //line 5
};
```

How much memory will be allocated for line 5 ,and will it be 1 memory block or 2 memory block since what it is pointing to is having two seperate integers.

Please help i am confused with self referencing pointers memory allocation.

Comment: It will be a size of a pointer to a structure (or just the same as any pointer on the "common" x86-like architecture). You can always ask the compiler about it by the way, by using `sizeof` operator.

Comment: Be careful when you tag `c` and `c++` the answer may be different between the 2 because these are different languages. In this case it is the same.

Comment: YOu can find this yourself: `std::cout << sizeof(struct node*) << "\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of an object pointer is always same in standard C++ regardless of what the pointed object contains. The size can vary between systems, but as a rule of thumb, a pointer is 64 bits on 64 bit programs, 32 bits on 32 bit programs and ... you hopefully get the pattern.

An analogy for this is addresses of buildings. The size of the building has no effect on the size of the address of the building.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 memories in there, one is the memory used to store the pointer in the struct, the other is the memory pointed by the struct.

The size of the pointer itself within the struct is `sizeof(struct node*)` which is usually a long int or 8 bytes (it might not be that, check for your system).

NO memory will be allocated for the pointer. It will likely be pointing to nullptr / 0. You are responsible for allocating that memory through malloc, new or any other allocation mechanism.

Comment: Oh shoot TIL, I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

The type of the pointer link is `struct node *`. So logically it is evident that the pointer will point to an object of the type `struct node`. So the allocated extent of memory pointed to by the pointer will be equal to `sizeof( struct node )`.

Though in general you may allocate an array of objects of the type `struct node` the first element of which will be pointed to by the pointer.:) In this case the memory extent will be equal to `N * sizeof( struct node )` where `N` is the number of elements in the allocated array.

On the other hand, as the pointer is a data member of the structure then it will occupy the part of the extent of memory allocated for an object of the type `struct node`. Usually size of a pointer is equal to 4 or 8 bytes depending on the used system.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node 
{ 
    int data1; 
    int data2;
    struct node* link; //line 5
};

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "sizeof( struct node ) = %zu\n", sizeof( struct node ) );
    printf( "sizeof( link ) = %zu\n", sizeof( struct node * ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( struct node ) = 16
sizeof( link ) = 8
```

Or the demonstrative program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node 
{ 
    int data1; 
    int data2;
    struct node* link; //line 5
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct node obj;
    
    printf( "sizeof( obj ) = %zu\n", sizeof( obj ) );
    printf( "sizeof( obj.link ) = %zu\n", sizeof( obj.link ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is similar to the output of the previous program

```
sizeof( obj ) = 16
sizeof( obj.link ) = 8
```

that is the size of an object of the type `struct node` is equal to `16` while its data member `link` has the size equal to 8.